# How to translate a dot product in a MATLAB for loop to R?

Tags: r, for-loop, dot-product

I have been trying for many hours now how to successfully translate this MATLAB dot product inside a for loop into RStudio. Here is the MATLAB code:

```
m = 24;
k = 24;
s = 449:
yhb= zeros(s-m+k,1);
for i = 1:s-m+k
     yhb(i,:)=dot(krf(7,1:i),hat(2,i:-1:1));
end
```

yhb is a 449 x 1 vector, krf is a 16 x 449 matrix, and hat is a 4 by 449 matrix. Here is the screenshot of the first few rows of yhb created from the for loop.

[screenshot of the first few rows of yhb created from the MATLAB for loop][1]

Here is the code that I first tried in RStudio:

```
m <- 24
k <- 24
s <- 449
yhb <- matrix(0,s-m+k,1)

for (i in 1:(s-m+k)) {
      yhb[i,] <- sum(krf[7,1:i]*hat[2,rev(hat)])
}
```

I am then getting an error message which is this:

**Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'sum': only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts**

I then realized that the MATLAB for loop above essentially makes these calculations to obtain the elements of yhb:

yhb[1,1] = krf[1,1]*hat[1,1]

yhb[2,1] = krf[1,1]*hat[1,2] + krf[1,2]*hat[1,1]

yhb[3,1] = krf[1,1]*hat[1,3] + krf[1,2]*hat[1,2] + krf[1,3]*hat[1,1]

so on and so forth.. How can I create a for loop such as this in R where the index is from 1:(s-m+k)?

I am stuck. Appreciate any help you can provide, please. Thank you so much.

Comment: `reverses the order of the elements in hat` you mean `rev(hat[2, ])` ?

Comment: Hello @rawr, when I try your suggestion using this command: `for (i in 1:(s-m+k)) { yhb[i,] <- sum(krf[7,1:i]*rev(hat[2,]))   
}` I am getting a warnings, and can't still replicate the one produced by the MATLAB for loop.

Comment: I think you want `yhb[i,] <- sum(krf[7,1:i]*hat[2,i:1])`

Comment: Your MATLAB code errors at `i = 426`. Are you sure the dimensions of `hat` are 4 x 425?

Comment: Hi jblood94, sorry hat is a 4 x 449 matrix. I have corrected my question. Thank you.

Comment: Many thanks, @jblood94. Your suggested command was the answer to my trouble.

Comment: I am new so how do mark that my question has been solved? I marked two up arrows, so I hope those are the ones. Thanks.

Comment: I put it into an answer if you want to mark that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `i:-1:1` in MATLAB becomes `i:1` in R, so the `for` loop should be:

```
for (i in 1:449) yhb[i] <- sum(krf[7, 1:i]*hat[2, i:1])
```